# Jenkins-swarm slaves go down

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

We have a large number of jenkins slaves setup vip jenkins-swarm plugin(auto-discover the master)

Recently, we started to see slaves going offline and existing jobs get stuck. We fixed it with restarting the master. However, it has been happening too frequently. Everything seems to be fine, no network issue nor gc issue.

Anyone?

On the jenkins slaves, we see this repeatity once the node become unavailable:

```
Retrying in 10 seconds
Attempting to connect to http://ci.foobar.com/jenkins/ 46185efa-0009-4281-89d2-c4018fa9240c with ID 5a0f1773
Could not obtain CSRF crumb. Response code: 404
Failed to create a slave on Jenkins CODE: 409
A slave called '10.9.201.89-5a0f1773' is already created and on-line
```